# How can I create an ast node for values in python?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm looking for a way to create ast nodes from a value stored in a variable.

I can do it for some types manually, for example

```
def to_ast_node(value):
    t = type(value)
    type_map = {
        int: ast.Num,
        float: ast.Num,
        str: ast.Str
    }
    ret_type = type_map.get(t, None)
    if ret_type:
        return ret_type(self.return_value)
```

But I'm wondering if there is a module/method to do that for any value, for example custom types, lists, dicts etc.

Thanks

Comment: For most types (all custom types, and even some built-in ones), there's no literal so at most you could try emitting code to re-create the object, which is very hairy, fragile and complex.

Comment: is there no way to "dump" the variable to ast?

Comment: The AST represents Python source code. What Python source code would you expect the result to look like?

Comment: I see the limitation with the custom types etc. I guess I would be happy with something like a pickled value for non simple types.

So maybe the Ast would be unpickling a binary blob?